# How do I make query with string list of firebase realtime databse

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a predefined `List<String>`. Now in my app I retrieved data from Firebase database. Generally I used:

```
DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    Query query = reference.child("Users").orderByChild("id").equalTo("string");
```

But for more stuff I want to filter data from my `List<String>`. So is this possible like below query?

```
Query query = reference.child("Users").orderByChild("id").equalTo(***String_exists_in_predefined_list***);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So is this possible like below query ??

No, it's not possible. You cannot pass a list of strings as the second argument to the `equalTo()` method because there is no such a method that accepts that. You need to iterate over the list and create a query for each one of those elements and merge the result client side.

**Edit:**

You need to loop through the list and create a query for each element:

```
for(String element : list) {
    Query query = reference.child("Users").orderByChild("id").equalTo(element);
}
```

Comment: ***You need to iterate over the list*** and create a query for each one of those elements and merge the result client side.

I didnt get this and out of my mind

Comment: Keep in mind that having multiple open queries is not nearly as slow as you may initially expect, as Firebase pipelines all queries and results over a single connection. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35931526/speed-up-fetching-posts-for-my-social-network-app-by-using-query-instead-of-obse/35932786#35932786

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks again puf for mentioning that.

Comment: if im not wrong..
loop will circular 100time. if my list has 100 element and firebase calling is also 100 time.

Comment: @tailor As Frank van Puffelen mentioned in his comment, this operation is no as slow as you might think. So you can go ahead with that.

Comment: So is there no any **direct query for this ?**

Comment: No, there is no "direct" query for that here, nor in Cloud Firestore.

Answer (score 0):

Get the string from your predefined list in oncreate. Call the method with your query and carry over the string and use it there.

Inside oncreate

```
String fromlist = [retrieve here];
queryData(fromlist);
```